# jQuery Regex to validate URL with or without http and suffix is required

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery validator plugin, I want to validate the URL on two conditions:
1. http/https should be optional
2. suffix is required (.com, .in etc);

currently I'm trying this method:

```
var urlregex = new RegExp("^(?!www | www\.)[A-Za-z0-9_-]+\.+[A-Za-z0-9.\/%&=\?_:;-]+$")
```

but this is not working with my condition.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
var urlregex = /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/;
```

Comment: I tried this, it is not working even after entering valid URL, it returns the error.

Comment: Can you share your invocation script.

Comment: Try now its working here.

var regex = /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/;
regex.test(https://'www.google.com');